# How to inject List of non-primitive Objects in Spring @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Hi Spring/SpringBoot/Yaml/Java Experts, I want to inject a list of values that belong to the class `Perm` in @Value

However, Spring fails to start my application and is throwing the error shown below:

`Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'myservice.api.perms' in value "${myservice.api.perms}"`

May I request you to help me as I am new to Spring, Spring Boot, and Yaml

```
# application.yaml file

myservice:
  api:
    perms:
      -
        name: xyz
        guid: abc
        index: 0
```

```
// Class file that wants to read a List<Perm> from the application.yaml file

@Slf4j
@Getter
@Service
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class MyService {

    @Value("${myservice.api.perms}")
    private List<Perm> perms;

    public List<Perm> getListOfPerms() {
        return perms;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Perm {

        @NotBlank
        private String name;

        @NotBlank
        private String guid;

        private int index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Lists can only hold references (non-primitives). So this wording is redundant in your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) in this case!

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("myservice.api")
@Getter
@Setter
@Validated
public class ApiProperties {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    @NotEmpty
    private List<@Valid Perm> perms;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Perm {

        @NotBlank
        private String name;

        @NotBlank
        private String guid;

        @NotNull
        @Positive
        private Integer index;

    }

}
```

More resources:

- [Guide to @ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) (Baeldung)
- [Type-safe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) (Spring reference)

Comment: Thank you times29. The above worked for me. I had to additionally tag the `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` annotation on the class and configure the annotation processor. Once I did that, I was only able to use my bean when I did the following: `private ApiProperties properties; 

  public MyService(@Qualifier("apiProperties") ApiProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
  }
`

Comment: @Jared glad to hear! The `@Qualifier("apiProperties")` shouldn't be necessary unless you have another `ApiProperties` bean with a differrent name!